Getting notification ID immediately after sending notification in Laravel 8
I'm working on a Laravel 8 application where I need to retrieve the notification ID immediately after sending a notification. However, I'm facing difficulties in obtaining the notification ID using the standard Laravel notification system.
// Controller method
public function roomCollabrationrequest(CollabrationRequestSend $request)
{
    // ... (existing code)

    $collabration = RoomCollabration::create([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'room_id' => $request->room_id,
        'status' => 'pending',
    ]);

    $receiver = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
    $notificationSent = $receiver->notify(new CollabrationRequestNotification($collabration));

    // Trying to get the notification ID
    $notificationId = $notificationSent->id;

    // ... (existing code)
}

// CollabrationRequestNotification.php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CollabrationRequestNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $collabration;

    public function __construct($collabration)
    {
        $this->collabration = $collabration;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        $userName = auth()->user()->user_name ?? auth()->user()->name;

        return [
            'tag' => 'collaboration',
            'message' => $userName . ' has Sent You a Collaboration Request',
            'collaboration_status' => 'pending',
            'collaboration_id' => $this->collabration->id,
            'profile_picture' => auth()->user()->profile_picture,
        ];
    }
}

In the controller method, after sending the notification using $receiver->notify(new CollabrationRequestNotification($collabration)), I'm trying to retrieve the notification ID using $notificationSent->id. However, this always returns null.
I've tried various approaches, including implementing the ShouldDatabase interface and defining the toDatabase method, but none of them seem to work.
Could someone please guide me on how to get the notification ID immediately after sending the notification in Laravel 8?
Additional Information:
Laravel Version: 8.x
Database: MySQL
I'd appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue.
I Tried ..
$notificationInstance = $receiver->notifyNow(new CollabrationRequestNotification($collabration));
